# Google app engine active instance count goes to zero

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using standard environment of Google app engine where I've used F1 instance class and set minimum instance =1 under auto scale section.
Although I've set minimum instance =1 but still I can see active instance count sometimes goes to zero.

Any reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs ( https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling ), you need to have a warmup handler, so it can make sure an instance is spun up:

> Warning: For this feature to function properly, you must make sure
> that warmup requests are enabled and that your application handles
> warmup requests.

Setting up warmup handler:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-warmup-requests

Example (Flask):

```
@app.route('/_ah/warmup')
def warmup():
    # Handle your warmup logic here, e.g. set up a database connection pool
    return '', 200, {}
```